# Error installing singularitygs on Windows

Tags: singularitygs

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>gem install singularity

Fetching: redis-2.2.2.gem (100%)

Fetching: redis-native_hash-0.2.2.gem (100%)

Fetching: i18n-0.6.9.gem (100%)

Fetching: json-1.8.1.gem (100%)

ERROR:  Error installing singularity:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Comment: Hey Chris, consider upvoting answers and selecting the one that helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

Please install `singularitygs` and not `singularity`. These are two completely different things.

`gem install singularitygs` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is right, you're installing the wrong gem. The correct one is `singularitygs`.

But the issue you've had is pretty general and you'll encounter it again and again.

The matter is that some gems require native extensions:  components that can't be served from RubyGems, but should be built in place. To build them, you need to have Ruby DevKit installed on your Windows machine.

Follow [this link](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) to learn what DevKit is and then proceed to installation instructions.

After you're done, native extensions will be built during the installation of gems that require the. Normally it, takes a lot of time, so don't cancel the installation due to a freeze: it's not frozen. :)